# How do I clear my urination chi when some dude is at the urinal next to me?

Tags: bathroom

Sometimes when I'm at a public urinal, if another dude comes mosey up next to me, I get stage-fright and can't go.  What can I do to clear my thoughts?

Comment: @JustDoIt Comments are not for answers. If you have an answer, please leave it below.

Comment: those comments are not lifehacks, therefore theyre not suitable answers. @michaelpri I'm following guidelines, please it's the third time a mod deletes my comments. I refuse to post as an answer something that's not a lifehack

Comment: @JustDoIt Then under what premise is your not-a-good-answer comment appropriate? Comments are not meant to be a means of posting half *sort-of-answers* to bypass the Stack Exchange-style vetting that is supposed to go with stuff we publish here.

Comment: Cause they're still solutions @RobertCartaino , they're just not life-hacks hence why I commented my solution. Please let's us discuss it in the meta [post](http://meta.lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/2628/whats-so-wrong-about-my-comments)

Answer (score 2):

Remember this video of waterfalls:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lcL678AASFc

Picturing waterfalls and remembering the sounds thereof will both relax you and remind you of your urgent purpose for being at the urinal.